# Import CSV to SQL - with datetime/timestamp

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, import, timestamp

I'm currently working on importing a CSV(with thousands of rows) into SQL. 
So far, I have created a table in SQL and populated it with column names, as well as data types corresponding to the column names(all of these correspond to the columns in the csv)

In this csv file, one of the column gives a timestamp in the form of: 
2/3/2019  12:00:00 AM (MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS)
The corresponding column I created in sql has a datatyoe if timestamp(6)

My next step is to right click on the table I just created in SQL and hit "Import Data" I then go through the steps of importing the csv to sql, however, the timestamps are not correctly imported. I know this because all of the timestamps in the csv are from February 3, 2019, and in SQL it ranges from
20-MAR-02 7:00:05 PM(DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS) to 20-APR-02 7:00:00 PM(DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS)

I don't know a way to get the format to match up from the csv(MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS) to SQL(DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS)

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!!

Edit: @Sean Lange: Thanks! When I try to use datetime(6)as a data type I get an error that says 00907:missing right parenthesis? If I try just datetime I get an error 00902: invalid datatype? Any thoughts?

Edit#2: Yes, I am using oracle, sorry the language on these websites confuses me sometimes because I'm still learning. Any help would still be wonderful, going through step by step specifically

Edit #3: Thank you for your help. Sorry once again for my lack of knowledge, I'm using oracle sql developer.
After creating the table incorrectly, I then typed these lines of code:

alter table table_name

alter column column_name to_timestamp(yourFieldName, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am');

However, I was given this error.

Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

I truly do appreciate all of your help, thank you all again!

I also tried to update the for[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bvUV.png)mat in the wizard and was given an error. Attached are screenshots explaining what I did

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE7o2.png)

I dont think the pictures are working, but the error said that the date format wasnt recognized.

Comment: This is because timestamp is NOT a datetime datatype. It is a synonym of rowversion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 It is also a horribly named datatype that has nothing to do with time of day. But I wonder if you are really using timestamp because you can't specify the size with that datatype. You should use datetime to hold datetime information.

Comment: With the recent edit it seems highly likely you are NOT using sql server but are in fact using Oracle. The error message is an Oracle error message. Which DBMS are you using??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what **client** you're using to connect to Oracle Database - TOAD? Oracle SQL Developer? Something else? ...So I can't give you specific step-by-step instructions.

However, your basic problem is that you need to convert from a text string to a timestamp, and for that you need to enter your date format string. Somewhere your "Import Data" wizard should have a step for either (a) entering an expression or (b) entering a date format.

The date format string you want is `'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'` (not case sensitive, you can use caps if you prefer, or pm instead of am).

The expression would be

```
to_timestamp(yourFieldName, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')
```